# How would I implement a trigger in SQL Server that writes to a json file every time an update happens?

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server

I have tables in SQL Server that I want to write to an archive table. I am adding triggers on insert and update to do so. I also want to have a live replication of those updates to a json file.

How could I continually append to a json file in SQL Server (almost like a log file)? Would I use `SqlDependency` or is there a newer way/better way?

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events

Additional explanation of why I want to do this: I need to build a web api off of that json archive file that way we are not pinging the database but instead are pinging a file disconnected to the database. Also some users want a straight up upload of that json file. It feels backwards so a different approach is welcome if you see one.

Comment: Trigger, insert in Service Broker queue, read queue with application, append to file (do not actually rewrite the JSON as that's stupidly expensive; just append one line per update and package the result in objects/arrays as necessary when streaming back). Solid, dependable, won't fail if the app isn't ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a CLR procedure that writes to the JSON, and call it from your existing triggers.

If you do this, I would write the CLR to work in an asynchronous fashion to avoid locking the table any longer than necessary while the trigger completes.